# JavaBean not being remembered throughout the session

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I'm currently learning JSP/Servelets. The following is code containing 2 JSP pages and a servlet, which works as follows:

1. JSP #1 requests user info, & passes it into a servlet.
2. The servlet Instantiates a JavaBean class, and passes it to the 2nd JSP, using the **Session** Object.
3. The 2nd JSP then displays the info that th user entered in the 1st JSP; the user can then   hit the **Return** button to return to the 1st JSP.

My Question is: I've read in various Tutorials (notably Murach's JSP, which this code is based on) that if the Javabean attributes are passed to the session object rather than the request object, the JavaBean's values should be maintained throughout the session. However when I return to the first page, the JB fields are empty. Am i doing anything wrong? I would appreciate any help!

The following is the code:

1st JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Email Application</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Join our Email list</h1>
    <p>To join our email list, enter your name and email address below.<br>
    Then, click on the Submit button</p>

    <form action="addToEmailList" method="post">
    <jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session" class="business.User"/>
        <table cellspacing="5" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">First name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName"
                    value = "<jsp:getProperty name="user" property="firstName"/>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Last name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName"
                    value = "<jsp:getProperty name="user" property="lastName"/>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Email address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="emailAddress"
                    value = "<jsp:getProperty name="user" property="emailAddress"/>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>I'm interested in these types of music:</td>
                <td><select name="music" multiple>
                        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
                        <option value="country">Country</option>
                        <option value="bluegrass">Bluegrass</option>
                        <option value="folkMusic">Folk Music</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
```

Servlet:

```
public class AddToEmailListServlet extends HttpServlet
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private HttpServletRequest request;
private HttpServletResponse response;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String emailAddress;
private String[] musicTypes;
private Music music;
private User user;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    this.request = request;
    this.response = response;
    setInstanceVariables();
    writeDataToFile();
    forwardResponseToJSPpage();
    System.err.println("Hello!");
}

private void setInstanceVariables()
{
    this.firstName = getFirstName();
    this.lastName = getLastName();
    this.emailAddress = getEmailAddress();
    this.musicTypes =  request.getParameterValues("music"); //getMusic();
    this.user = new User(firstName,lastName,emailAddress);
}

private String getFirstName()
{
    return  request.getParameter("firstName");
}

private String getLastName()
{
    return request.getParameter("lastName");
}

private String getEmailAddress()
{
    return request.getParameter("emailAddress");
}


private void writeDataToFile() throws IOException
{
    String path = getRelativeFileName();
    UserIO.add(user,path);
}

private String getRelativeFileName()
{
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");
    return path;
}

private void forwardResponseToJSPpage() throws ServletException, IOException
{
    if(this.emailAddress.isEmpty()||this.firstName.isEmpty()||this.lastName.isEmpty())
    {
        String url = "/validation_error.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
    else
    {
    music = new Music(musicTypes); 

    HttpSession session = this.request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("music", music);
    session.setAttribute("user", user);

    String url = "/display_email_entry.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    doPost(request,response);
}

}
```

2nd JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ include file="/header.html" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Email Application</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Thanks for joining our email list</h1>

     <p>Here is the information that you entered:</p>

<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session" class="business.User"/>
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">First name:</td>
        <td><jsp:getProperty name="user" property="firstName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Last name:</td>
        <td><jsp:getProperty name="user" property="lastName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Email Address:</td>
        <td><jsp:getProperty name="user" property="emailAddress"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<p>We'll use the Email to otify you whenever we have new releases of the following types of music:</p>

<c:forEach items="${music.musicTypes}" var="i">
    <c:out value="${i}"></c:out><br/>
</c:forEach>

<p>To enter another email address, click on the Back <br>
button in your browser or the Return button shown <br>
below.</p>

<form action="join_email_list.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Return">
</form>
</body>
<%@ include file="/footer.html" %>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you returning to the first page? I think you're missing a "Controller" servlet to populate the user value in the session.

Comment: Mutable (per request) instance variables in a servlet are a no-go... fix that one first.